# Is multiple left join is better and faster with same table ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

```sql
SELECT
    E.Id, 
    E.Name, 
    CASE EL.Application_Level WHEN 33 then 1 ELSE 0 END As MyDisplayName,
    CASE EL1.Application_Level WHEN 34 then 1 ELSE 0 END As FoodTag
FROM
    Entity E 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Countries CN ON cn.id=E.COUNTRY_ID  
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity_Levels EL ON E.ID = EL.Entity_ID AND EL.Application_Level = 33
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity_Levels EL1 ON E.ID = EL1.Entity_ID AND EL1.Application_Level = 34
```

Instead of two join with same table i want to use OR Condition, becasue there will be more application levels added and i dont want to do add more joins.

Is there anyway i can use or condition and one join and merge multiple records to one record.

Comment: Multiple `left join`s is much the better way to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i can have more then 10 application levels. Still you prefer that many left join ?

Comment: try just putting `or` in for two of the joins and see what happens to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show any sample data, this is only a guess, but it looks like you could do something like this with only 1 join to the `ENTITY_LEVELS` table:

```
SELECT
E.Id, 
max(E.Name) as Name,
max(case when EL.application_level = 33 then 1 else 0 end) as MyDisplayName,
max(case when EL.application_level = 34 then 1 else 0 end) as FoodTag,
max(case when EL.application_level = 35 then 1 else 0 end) as RandomOtherThing
from entity E
INNER JOIN dbo.Countries CN ON cn.id=E.COUNTRY_ID  
LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity_Levels EL ON E.ID = EL.Entity_ID 
group by E.Id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT E.Id
    ,E.Name
    ,CASE WHEN EL.Application_Level = 33
             THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END AS MyDisplayName
    ,CASE WHEN EL.Application_Level = 34
            THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END AS FoodTag
FROM Entity E WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN dbo.Countries CN WITH(NOLOCK) ON CN.id=E.COUNTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Entity_Levels EL WITH(NOLOCK) ON E.ID=EL.Entity_ID
```

Comment: you should give brief what you did special.

Comment: Why add with(nolock)?..any specific reason?

Comment: Nothing did special just remove one left join and remove condition (AND EL.Application_Level = 33) from first left join.

Comment: this will give multiple results for the same record.. If entity_Levels has two records ..

Comment: Then you have to use query answered by hellion